# RenderViewport#0d172 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter

This is my Flutter app UI:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Pow.png)

and after I take data from Firebase everything disappeared, and nothing shown just the appBar.
**Build Method:**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Recipes Menu'),
    leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[50],
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 16,),
      search(),
      SizedBox(height: 8,),
      SizedBox(height:6),
    //  foodCard(),
       const Divider(),
    ], ),  ); }
```

this is my code:

```
Widget foodCard() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: InkWell (
        onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, 
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RecipeScreen()));},
                child: Column(
                 mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
                 children: [
                   Expanded(
                   ListView.builder(itemCount: allRecipes.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 8.0,
            shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
            child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    child: FittedBox(
                          child: Material(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              elevation: 8.0,
                              shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      width: 250,
                                      height: 250, 
                                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                            placeholder: kTransparentImage, height: 200,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                             image:
                                              "https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/087d17eb-500e-4b26-abd1-4f9ffa96a2c6.jpg")),
                                  Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text(allRecipes[index].name,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                                      ),
                                      Text(allRecipes[index].about,
                                       softWrap: true,),
                                      Divider(),
                                      ButtonBar( alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          FlatButton(
                                            child: Text('Like',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple)),
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                          ),
                                          FlatButton(
                                            child: Text('Dislike',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple)),                                      onPressed: () {}, ),
                                        ] ]),))],)))),);},), ],), ) ); 
}
```

**and I have this long error:**

```
ListView
```

lib\screens\menuScreen.dart:47
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e62d4 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e62d4 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView

error message:

```
  RenderFlex#7f39a relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← _RawMouseRegion ← MouseRegion ← Semantics ← _FocusMarker ← Focus ← _ActionsMarker ← ⋯, parentData: <none> (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=340.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)
```

The creator information is set to:
Column ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ←
_RawMouseRegion ← MouseRegion ← Semantics ← _FocusMarker ← Focus ← _ActionsMarker ← ⋯
See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Column

**the error message is too long, what should I do?**

Comment: Sorry why do you have ```ListView``` inside ```ListView``` ?

Comment: there was an error about vertical viewport given unbounded height, so I found this solution so  I tried it. @ikerfah

Comment: Try to replace first ```ListView``` by ```Column``` and then wrap the second ```ListView``` by ```Expanded``` and tell me what happened.

Comment: I did now but the UI still show nothing except appBar, I updated the question, there is another error @ikerfah

Comment: Add ```mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min``` to the ```Column``` . could you update the code now ?

Comment: nothing changed :( @ikerfah

Comment: I have to see the new code new , not the error.

Comment: Oh, okay I updated it now @ikerfah

Comment: If you comment the call for ```foodCard```, the issue disappear ? if yes, could you put your ```build``` method

Comment: well the error disappeared, I posted my build method. @ikerfah

Comment: Replace ```body: ListView(``` by ```body:Column(``` and then wrap ```foodCard()``` by ```Expanded```

Comment: should I remove them from foodCard?

Comment: Keep them for the moment

Comment: it is worked! but the view of it is not the same! I added an image at the top, could you check it please?

Comment: Show me the final code please,

Comment: okay I Just Updated the build method like  you told me, there is nothing else new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your try this code after the discussion we had in comments, Could you use the same code and told me ? please be sure that you restarted the app not hot reload

```
Widget foodCard() {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: allRecipes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Material(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                      borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 8.0,
                            shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                    width: 250,
                                    height: 250,
                                    child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                        height: 200,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                        image:
                                        "https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/087d17eb-500e-4b26-abd1-4f9ffa96a2c6.jpg")),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text(
                                        allRecipes[index].name,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        allRecipes[index].about,
                                        softWrap: true,
                                      ),
                                      Divider(),
                                      ButtonBar(
                                          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            FlatButton(
                                              child: Text('Like',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color:
                                                      Colors.deepPurple)),
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                            ),
                                            FlatButton(
                                              child: Text('Dislike',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color:
                                                      Colors.deepPurple)),
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

build

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Recipes Menu'),
          leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[50],
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            // search(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 6),
            Expanded(child: foodCard()),
            Divider(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: I am having errors from return ChangeNotifierProvider<CardsProvider>.value(.....

Comment: i'm so sorry, i copied unused code of mine because i was testing for you, i updated my answer

Comment: It is Okay, it is working like before. But when I fetch the text from firebase UI change again. I will add screenshots, check them please

Comment: If it was because of ```"allRecipes[index].name"``` i updated my code

Comment: yes,  there is a something with the text, it just like the photo I showed you before, for now I don't know if the images are visible for you or not! they aren't visible for me even when I try to upload them many times

Comment: can I send them by email or another way?

Comment: it is visible here the same as the first screenshot you attached, and for the image it might be because of your internet it is not loading ?

Comment: but why the text is going in just one line and not multilines?

Comment: can you show me screenshot when you enter a long text in `Text(
                                        allRecipes[index].about,) `

Comment: Just to not go out of the original topic of the question , you can add ```maxLines:2``` to the ```Text```

Comment: Thank you for helping and sorry for take more than hour from your time :)